# Splitting the string with multiple unique spliter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

One of the columns is string.
I want to split the string but it does not have a unique character to use as a spliter.
Below is the sample data frame:

```
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','David'],'Occupation':['CEO','Dep Dir'],'Contact':['HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456','Off-Mobile Ph 152:256']},`)
```

What I wanted to do is to split Contact.
My desired output will be as follow:
[image: My Desired output]

I used the following code to split at '-'.

```
df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df.Contact.str.split('[-]',expand=True)
```

But the output is not the format that I wanted.
Can anyone help me with that it is a specific problem which I cannot find it.
Thanks,

Zep

Comment: Does `df.Contact.str.split('-',expand=True)` work for you?

Comment: Hi Sergey. It did not work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `-` for 2 columns and then [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by last whitespace:

```
df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df.Contact.str.split('-',expand=True)
df['Contact2'] = df['Contact2'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
print (df)
    Name Occupation                  Contact Contact1   Contact2
0   John        CEO  HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456    HP No  Mobile Ph
1  David    Dep Dir    Off-Mobile Ph 152:256      Off  Mobile Ph
```

Comment: Oh Jezrael.
You again. Thanks a lot.
Would you a bit explain how rsplit work?

Comment: It is split from right side, if parameter `n=1` it split by first whitespace from back.

Comment: Let's say if no-Mobile 012:456. Then I have to use n=0, isn't it?

Comment: no, it is `n=1` because need split by `no-Mobile` and `012:456`

Answer (score 1):

First slice the unwanted data and then use `split` (Assuming the length of data Ph is constant):

```
df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df.Contact.str[:-8].str.split('[-]',expand=True)
```

If data after Ph is not constant use `extract` on alphabets and space:

```
df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df.Contact.str.split('[-]',expand=True)
df['Contact2'] = df.Contact2.str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)')[0].str.rstrip()
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','David'],
                   'Occupation':['CEO','Dep Dir'],
                   'Contact':['HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456','Off-Mobile Ph']},)

print(df)
    Name Occupation                  Contact
0   John        CEO  HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456
1  David    Dep Dir            Off-Mobile Ph

df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df.Contact.str.split('[-]',expand=True)
print(df)

    Name Occupation                  Contact Contact1           Contact2
0   John        CEO  HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456    HP No  Mobile Ph 123:456
1  David    Dep Dir            Off-Mobile Ph      Off          Mobile Ph

df['Contact2'] = df.Contact2.str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)')[0].str.rstrip()
print(df)

    Name Occupation                  Contact Contact1   Contact2
0   John        CEO  HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456    HP No  Mobile Ph
1  David    Dep Dir            Off-Mobile Ph      Off  Mobile Ph
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep,
The length is not constant too.
This is where i got trouble

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.I will check it out.

Comment: @Zephyr Check the update it works even if number present or not.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.
Appreciate your help and I have multiple solutions to solve my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
df[['Contact1','Contact2']] = df['Contact'].str.split('-' or ' ',expand=True)
df.Contact2 = df.Contact2.str.split(' ').str[:-1].apply(' '.join)
```

Out:

```
              Contact       Name    Occupation  Contact1    Contact2
0   HP No-Mobile Ph 123:456 John    CEO          HP No     Mobile Ph
1   Off-Mobile Ph 152:256   David   Dep Dir       Off      Mobile Ph
```

Comment: Hi Kiran,
Thanks for the advice. I do not want the number behing ph.